Why i my page is rerendering when i toogle side bar?
I facing rerendering problem when i toogle my sidebar. When i scroll actions on page than i toogle it than it is causing rerendering issues, How i fix this problem?
you can click here checkout quick loom video of issue
Current setup:
const ApiExplorerWrapper = (props) => {

const [openapi, setOpenapi] = useState({});
const { leftSideBarOpenByClick } = useContext(Context);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const appid = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    getAppData(appid);
  }, []);

//function to get the app data

return (
    <div className="api-explorer-wrapper" style={{ display: "flex", paddingLeft: userdata?.support ? leftSideBarOpenByClick ? 280 : 100 : 0, paddingTop: userdata.support ? 30 : 0,  transition: "padding-left 0.3s ease",}}>
      {isAppDataLoaded ? (
        <ApiExplorer openapi={openapi}/>
      ) : (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            height: "calc(100vh - 68px)",
            width: "100%",
          }}
        >
          {skeletonLoader}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ApiExplorer.jsx
const ApiExplorer = ({ openapi, globalUrl }) => {
  const [actions, setActions] = useState([]);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const [serverurl, setServerUrl] = useState("");

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (openapi !== undefined && openapi !== null) {
      parseIncomingOpenapiData(openapi);
    }
  }, []);


const ActionExecutionAndResponse = ({ ExampleBody, setExampleBody }) => {
      const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState({});
      const [filteredActions, setFilteredActions] = useState([]);
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // Add loading state
      const loadAction = 2;
      const loadedAction = useRef(null);

      // Set initial ExampleBody
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (!ExampleBody && actions.length) {
          setExampleBody(actions[0]?.body);
        }
      }, [ExampleBody, setExampleBody]);

      const loadMoreActions = () => {
        if (isLoading || filteredActions.length >= actions.length) return; // Prevent loading if already loading or all actions are loaded
        setIsLoading(true);
        setFilteredActions((prevActions) => {
          const newActions = actions.slice(prevActions.length, prevActions.length + loadAction);
          return [...prevActions, ...newActions];
        });
        setIsLoading(false);
      };

      // Handle scroll event
      const scrollPosition = useRef(0);

      const handleScroll = () => {
        const actionContainer = loadedAction.current;
        if (
          actionContainer &&
          actionContainer.scrollTop + actionContainer.clientHeight >= actionContainer.scrollHeight - 10
        ) {
          loadMoreActions();
        }
        scrollPosition.current = actionContainer.scrollTop;
      };

      // Restore scroll position on rerender
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (loadedAction.current) {
          loadedAction.current.scrollTop = scrollPosition.current;
        }
      }, [filteredActions]);


      // Add scroll event listener on mount
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const actionContainer = loadedAction.current;

        if (actionContainer) {
          actionContainer.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        }
        return () => {
          if (actionContainer) {
            actionContainer.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
          }
        };
      }, []);

      // Initial load of actions
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        loadMoreActions();
      }, []);

    
      return (
        <div ref={loadedAction} style={{ width: "100%", height: '80vh', overflowY:'auto', marginLeft: 10, alignItems: "center" }}>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 1920, margin: 0, padding: 0}}>
          {/* <div
            style={{
              position: "fixed",
              top: 0,
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#1a1a1a",
              zIndex: 1000,
              padding: "10px 0 10px 10px",
            }}
          > */}
            <h1>
              {info?.title ? (
                <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <img
                    src={openapi?.info["x-logo"]}
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    alt="app logo"
                    style={{ marginLeft: 20, borderRadius: 8 }}
                  />
                  <Typography style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 700, marginLeft: 20 }}>
                    {info.title}
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              ) : (
                "API Explorer"
              )}
            </h1>
          {/* </div> */}
      
          <div style={{ paddingTop: 20,}}> 
          {filteredActions.map((action, index) => (
            <Action
              key={index}
              action={action}
              index={index}
              serverurl={serverurl}
              setApiResponse={setApiResponse}
              setExampleBody={setExampleBody}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

        </div>
      
        <ActionResponse apiResponse={apiResponse} ExampleBody={ExampleBody} />
      </div>
      );
    };

const ApiActionPage = ()=>{

    const [ExampleBody, setExampleBody] = useState(actions[0]?.body);

    return (
      <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', width:  '100%', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
        <ActionsList setExampleBody={setExampleBody}/>
        <ActionExecutionAndResponse ExampleBody={ExampleBody} setExampleBody={setExampleBody}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: "calc(100vh - 70px)",
      }}
    >
      <ApiActionPage/>
    </div>
  );
};

I am tracking left sidebar open by click or not by using context api on other pages it is working smoothly but it is not working well on this page
** What is Expected Behaviour? **
When i am scrolling the actionexecutionandresponse and if it is loaded 10 action (by default it loads 2 as i scroll than it load next 2) than after click to leftsidbar it should not be set to its default value 2 it should be 10.

I tried to add run useEffect when hash changes url and scroll to the id which matches the hash but because it is rerendering and i am using lazy loading to load the actions it is causing problem.
I used profiler to track which component is rerendering but didn't find exactly which component is causing this rerender

